# How can I create a function to determine the current video Url from youtube?

Tags: java, android, android-youtube-api

How can I create a function to determine the video URL which is currently playing on YouTube.

I am trying to create a youtube minimizer app but don't know how to get the current video's URL which is playing.

Please help me